# blueimp, jquery-file-upload, custom button in file list

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I have my blueimp plugin working and now I want besides the "delete button" a "make-profile-pic" button. I already have the server side logic. Of course I can make a seperate ajax call but I am thinking there should be a clean way through blueimp.

Here is the relevant part from the x-tmpl:

```
<!-- added new table cell -->
<td data-url="{%=file.mainimageUrl%}">
   {% if (file.mainfoto == 1) { %}
      <span id="profilepic">Profielfoto</span>
   {% }else  { %}
      <button class="btn btn-info change-main-image" data-type="CHANGE_THE_MAIN_IMAGE" data-url="{%=file.mainimageUrl%}"  {% if (file.main_image_with_credentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
           <span>Maak Profielfoto</span>
         </button>
   {% } %}
</td>
<!-- existing table cell for reference-->
<td>
{% if (file.deleteUrl) { %}
  <button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="{%=file.deleteType%}" data-url="{%=file.deleteUrl%}">
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
        <span>Verwijder</span>
  </button>
  {% } else { %}
  <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
     <span>Cancel</span>
   </button>
   {% } %}
  </td>
```

So the two issues I have here are:

- The make-main-image button is not triggering a click (while the delete button seems to trigger on the fact button class="delete")
- When I hack the make-main-image button by adding the delete class, all is working server side but the filelist is not being refreshed